# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

After passing the product ID I'm being redirected to the product details page. In that page, I have details of the product such as name, destination, price and date etc. As I'm using `redux` and getting the data from `mongodb` the date is saved as `2021-11-23T18:00:00.000Z` this format. So after fetching the data in my product details page I used `flight?.data?.date.split("T")[0]` to only show the date. But after clicking the button to go to the product details page it shows the following error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`. But when I remove the `split` part from the code it is working fine. I guess the only reason is the code is running before the data is loaded. So for that I tried to show loading spinner before the data loads by dispatching loading action. But it isn't working. I've used `redux thunk` for other actions that is why I've added async in Action. Otherwise it gives me `dispatch is not defined`.

**Details page**

```
import { CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getFlight, loadingStatus } from "../../actions/flights";
import "./Details.css";

const FlightDetails = () => {
  const flight = useSelector((state) => state.flights);
  console.log("flight", flight.loading);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadingStatus(true));
    dispatch(getFlight(id));
    dispatch(loadingStatus(false));
  }, [id, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="details_parent">
      {flight.loading ? (
        <CircularProgress />
      ) : (
        <div className="details_container">
          <div className="form_data">
            <span>From</span>
            <h3>{flight?.data?.from}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="form_data">
            <span>To</span>
            <h3>{flight?.data?.to}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="form_data">
            <span>Airline</span>
            <h3>{flight?.data?.airline}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="form_data">
            <span>Trip type</span>
            <h3>{flight?.data?.flightType}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="form_data">
            <span>Date(yyyy-mm-dd)</span>
            <h3>{flight?.data?.date.split("T")[0]}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="form_data">
            <span>Price</span>
            <h1>${flight?.data?.price}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FlightDetails;
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_FLIGHTS":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };

    case "GET_FLIGHT":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };

    case "CREATE_FLIGHT":
      return { ...state, data: { ...action.payload } };

    case "SEARCH":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload };

    case "LOADING":
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

**Actions**

```
export const loadingStatus = (status) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "LOADING",
    payload: status,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting separate actions for change the loading state I've set the dispatching before getting the data in actions. And after the promise is returned I've again set the dispatch to false.

**Actions to get the specific flight data**

```
export const getFlight = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "LOADING",
      payload: true,
    });

    const { data } = await api.fetchFlight(id);

    dispatch({
      type: "GET_FLIGHT",
      payload: data,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: "LOADING",
      payload: false,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

React runs a first render before running any `useEffect` calls. Change your initial loading state to true.

```js
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: true,
};
```

Comment: Changed the state to `true`..Now it just showing the loading spinner...also tried removing the first `dispatch(loadingStatus(true))` but the problem remains same

Comment: That means loading is not getting set to false? That's weird. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: this is the error I'm getting - [link](https://ibb.co/W3DmYtP)

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using `flight?.data?.date?.split("T")[0]`

but in this case you have to set loading in initial data of reducer to true

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: true,
};
```

Comment: I've changed the state to `true` but it either shows me the spinner only or shows the same error

Comment: you have to set loading `false` after fetching data in reducer. like this `case "GET_FLIGHTS":
      return { ...state, data: action.payload, loading: false };`